# iPhone has stopped updating apps automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, auto-update

I have to open the App Store and tap *Update* to keep all of the apps up to date. There is always a big list of apps waiting to be updated, which takes quite a while to complete. This issue seems to have started around the release of iOS 9.

- The option for *Automatic Downloads* is ticket under *Settings > iTunes & App Stores*;
- Connecting to Wi-Fi has not resolved the issue;
- The instructions displayed on Apple’s support page has not resolved the issue;
- *Reset All Settings* has not resolved the issue.

There seem to be countless of people with this issue if you search the Internet. Unfortunately, none of the suggested resolutions by users have helped in my case. Could *Erase All Content and Settings* really be the only way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the App Store cache?  In the App Store app, tap the 'Update' button 10 times.  You'll see a flash of the screen as the cache is flushed.  Restart your iPhone and see if this helps.

Comment: @fbara Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have tried this method. It has not changed a thing, unfortunately.

Comment: If you've tried all other methods, as you indicated, then completely resetting your iPhone might be your only option.  If you do the complete reset and then restore from a backup, you might be putting the problem right back on your iPhone.  I would recommend doing a backup first and only doing the restore from backup if this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @fbara I was hoping to be able to avoid resetting my iPhone, especially for something like this, but it seems to be the only way for now. In any case, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was in the middle of relocating, I had updated my country amongst other personal information in my Apple ID. It appears installed apps stop updating until you reinstall them from the App Store for the new country even if the app is available under the very same name. You will be informed App Store switches country upon opening App Store for the first time after updating country in your Apple ID.

I have rung Apple about this issue, and they did not have much of a solution other than reinstalling the apps.
You could switch back to your old address to have automatic updates resume, but keep in mind your new ‘foreign’ payment details (ie credit cards) will not be accepted. At the time, I was told there is no way around this. I hope Apple changes this policy in the future as it is the only service which does not accept my foreign issued Mastercard to this day.

Answer (score 2):

Auto app update works only when the iPhone is plugged in to power.

Comment: This was indeed the issue for me. I always charge my phone on airplane mode, which means apps do not update automatically. Does anyone know if there is a way to have apps update even while not charging?

Answer (score 0):

The comment above makes some sense. My auto-update seemed to not be working since I switched to wireless charging. If I plug it in AND have it on wifi it does the auto-updates.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Be sure to either edit the post nending comment or incorporate the relevant part of the answer in yours. There is no durable “above” since people can sort answers three ways and they can get edited and reordered.